# OpenACC call to cuMemFreeHost returned error

Tags: openacc

I'm using PGI C Compiler--pgcc v16.10.0 64-bit--to learn how to program with OpenACC

Here is my code to simulate the process of particle transport

```
typedef struct {
    double position;
    double direction;
    double weight;
    int cell;
    int group;
    int alive;
    } Particle;

int size = 100000;             // number of particles to be simulated
int tot = (int) (1.3 * size);  // this variable limits the maximum of next generation particles
int capacity = 0;              // this variable indicates the actual number of next generation particles

/* particles to be simulated */
Particle *par = (Particle *) malloc(size * sizeof(Particle));

/* next generation particles produced */
particle *next = (Particle *) malloc(tot * sizeof(Particle));

/* initialization */
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    par[i].position = rand1() * 100.0;  // random number between 0.0~1.0
    par[i].direction = rand2();         // random number between -1.0~1.0
    par[i].weight = 1.0;
    par[i].cell = 2;
    par[i].group = rand1() > 0.5 ? 1 : 2;
    par[i].alive = 1;
}

/* some parameters used in simulation */
double keff = 1.0;
double tracklength, collision, absorption;

/* start simulating */
int generation;
for (generation = 1; generation <= 100; generation++){
    int CellID, MatID, GroupID;
    int k;   // k-th particle to be simulated
    #pragma acc parallel copy(capacity) copyin(par[0:size],size, keff) copyout(next[0:tot])
    #pragma acc loop reduction(+:tracklength, collision, absorption)
    for (k = 0; k < size; k++){
        /* do some calculating with par[k] */
        /* secondary particle produced under certain circumstances */
        if (condition){
            next[capacity].position = par[k].position;
            next[capacity].direction = rand2();
            next[capacity].weight = 1.0;
            next[capacity].cell = par[k].cell;
            next[capacity].group = rand1() < 0.9 ? 1 : 2;
            next[capacity].alive = 1;
            capacity++;
        }
    }
    /* after simulation of current generation, update the parameters */
    keff = ........          // one formula to update keff

    size = capacity;
    capacity = 0;
    tot = (int) (1.3 * size);
    free(par);
    par = next;
    next = (Particle *) malloc(tot * sizeof(Particle));
}

free(par);
free(next);
```

i compiled the code with

`pgcc -acc -Minfo=accel -ta=tesla:cc30,time -O0 main.c -o test`

and get information below:

`Loop carried dependence of par->alive, par->cell, par->direction, par->position, par->weight, par->group prevents parallelization
Loop carried dependence of par->direction, par->group, par->position prevents vectorization
Loop carried reuse of next->position prevents parallelization`

and then run the executable `./test`

an error occurred

`call to cuMemFreeHost returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution`

i have no idea how to work it out[SAD].

BTW the code runs well and returns the correct result when compiled by gcc ignoring #pragma

Comment: Since your code isn't complete, it's difficult to give a complete answer.  For "next", the compiler is correct in that you do have a loop dependency given the index variable, "capacity", value is dependent upon the previous iteration of the "k" loop.  You'll want to use an atomic capture of capacity, store it to a private scalar, and use this scalar as the "next" index.  My assumption is that the "par[k]" loop dependencies are coming from an omitted inner loop, not the "k" loop.  Again, a reproducible example would help.

Comment: Note that an "Illegal address" error typically occurs due to an out-of-bounds error or when accessing a host address on the device.  There are other causes, such as running out of heap space, but I doubt that's causing your error.  Most likely it will go away once you fix your loop dependency issues.